# iOS: lldb EXC_BAD_ACCESS Custom Cell

Tags: ios, memory-management, exc-bad-access, lldb

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LibraryListingCell";

    InSeasonCell *cell = (InSeasonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InSeasonCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [_cell autorelease];
        _cell = nil;
    }
    if(_dataController!=NULL){
        Product *productAtIndex = [_dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Configure the cell...
        if (productAtIndex.name != nil && productAtIndex.week != nil && productAtIndex.image != nil) {
            cell.name.text = productAtIndex.name;
            cell.week.text = productAtIndex.week;
            cell.image.image = productAtIndex.image;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Message ERROR for **cell.name.text cell.week.text cell.image.text**. Pretty sure it is a memory management error. I have retained and released properly to the best of my knowledge. The application will crash upon launch, sometimes it loads everything fine, but when you scroll it crashes. Any help or pointers about memory management is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
 if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InSeasonCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [_cell autorelease];
    _cell = nil;
  }
```

You sent autorelease message and set it to nil, later you are trying to access that released `cell`.

I think it should be as:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LibraryListingCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: _cell is a custom UITableViewCell and I access it as an IBOutlet. I dont think I have to release an IBOutlet or alloc one. I will try to use the IBOutlet without releasing it.

Comment: I was using this tutorial http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/customize-that-uiviewcell-part-1-using-interface-builder/.

Comment: There is a custom cell .h .m and xib file. How would I load that (custom xib) instead of creating a new UITableViewCell

Comment: Found it. it is in the docs now "Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files" [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)