# iOS: Custom Cell lldb Memory access error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, lldb

Still having trouble accessing variables to load into a custom cell. I have a xib, .h, .m named InSeasonCell. I have a IBOutlet InSeasonCell *_cell; in .h of rootviewcontroller. I get lldb error for accessing my productAtIndex values. Any help would be great. I was told to read the Table View Programming Guide.

I create

```
_dataController = [[InSeasonProductDataController alloc] init];
```

Which is init in the rootviewcontroller but passed to an other object which populates it with Product objects.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InSeasonCell";

    InSeasonCell *cell = (InSeasonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _cell;
        _cell = nil;
    }
    if(_dataController!=nil){
        Product *productAtIndex = [_dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Configure the cell...
            cell.name.text = productAtIndex.name;
            cell.week.text = productAtIndex.week;
            cell.image.image = productAtIndex.image;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I looked through my code and found that I am passing an object created in one class to the other. for example:

```
-(id)initWithDataController:(InSeasonProductDataController *)dataController spinner:      (UIActivityIndicatorView *)spinner{
       if(self = [super init]){
           _dataController = [dataController retain];
           _spinner = [spinner retain];
       }
       return self;
}
```

_dataController gets populated with Product objects later in this method and is released.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726970/ios-lldb-exc-bad-access-custom-cell, for which you already accepted an answer?

Comment: Note that using `registerNib:...` is a far easier method to load custom table view cells, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591474/1187415.

Comment: Tried using the example but I get -[UITableView registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I'll keep looking

Comment: `registerNib:...` is only available on iOS >= 5, perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: Yes I am using IOS6.1

Comment: You used the wrong method. `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is for table views, `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` is for collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My Product object initialized variables which I had to do a copy for each variable passed in. This got rid of the lldb error.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error you need in your xib file click on cell prototype and in Attribute inspection > Identifier insert the same name as you have in .m file (I write down "cell"):

in method:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  .......
  Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
  Cell = [[MainCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];